# Error as TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I tried running the KerasClassifier in my conv autoencoder for denoising to do the hyperparameter tuning but faced this error stated above.

The code and the logs are being mentioned below

**code**-

```
# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, verbose=0)

# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(x_train_noisy, y_train)


# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

**logs-**

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-53-1bc830769836> in <module>
      4 param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
      5 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=2, cv=3)
----> 6 grid_result = grid.fit(x_train_noisy, y_train)
      7 # summarize results
      8 print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

     C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 



TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Comment: Please can you refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320839/getting-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-rlock-objects/64340861#64340861) answer may help you. If it doesn't can you share complete code to replicate your issue so that we can help you. Thanks!